# Exercise in Atiyah (localization)

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let me refer you to:

http://www-users.math.umd.edu/~karpuk/chap3solns.pdf

Page 2, ex. 4

Can you please explain the following step:

$tb=f(s')b=s'b$

Why $f(s')=s'$ ?

Thanks

Comment: @user6495: That is a 16-page document. You need to be more specific about where.

Comment: @Zev Chonoles: sorry, just edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** We have a map $f:A\rightarrow B$. This makes $B$ into an $A$-module. What is the definition of "$ab$", for $a\in A$ and $b\in B$?

Comment: ab=f(a)b, right? Thanks! Damn it. can't believe I forgot this.

Comment: @user 6495: Exactly right. Don't worry, happens to all of us :)